# How to use substr(...) for BIT(...) data type columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(10)  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1001100111 |
| 2       | 0111000101 |
| 3       | 0001101010 |
| 4       | 1111111011 |
+---------+------------+
```

Now I'm trying to get third digit *(left to right)* from those number. Example:

```
1001100111
  ^ // I want to get 0
```

So it is expected result:

```
+--------------------+
| substr(numb, 3, 1) |
+--------------------+
| 0                  |
| 1                  |
| 0                  |
| 1                  |
+--------------------+
```

---

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(numb, 3, 1) FROM numbers
```

But it doesn't work. because `bit(10)` isn't string and `SUBSTR()` cannot parse it. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Convert it to a string first...

Comment: Would it be OK to find 8-th digit from the right instead?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes ..

Comment: If you want to use string operations, then just store the value as `char(10)`.  If you are going to store bits, then use bit operations -- MySQL has good support for them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right ..! I will change `BIT(10)` to `CHAR(10)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could use `substr` after converting to `varchar`, a simpler approach for `BIT(...)` data type it to use bit operators.

Since according to your comment it is OK to extract 8-th bit from the right, rather than the third bit from the left, this will produce the expected result:

```
select id, (x>>7)&1
from test
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fce0/1/0)

> Is it possible to I update just one of its digits? I mean I want to update seventh digit (right to left) from `1001011101` and make it `0`?

You can set a single bit to zero like this:

```
UPDATE test SET x = x & b'1110111111' WHERE id=3
```

Position of 0 indicates the bit you are setting to zero.

If you want to set it to `1`, use

```
UPDATE test SET x = x | b'0001000000' WHERE id=3
```

You can have more than one zero in the first example if you would like to set multiple bits to zero. Similarly, you can have more than one `1` in the second example if you need to set multiple bits to `1`.

Comment: May you please tell me what's `&1`? Actually this part of your query is really hard for me `(x>>8)&1`

Comment: @stack I edited the answer, it should be a shift by 7, not by 8. `>>7` means "shift to the right by seven". It drops rightmost seven bits. `&1` is a masking operation. It means "bitwise and with 1", or simply "take the least significant bit". Overall, the expression means "drop the last seven bits, and keep the next bit alone".

Comment: As a advise, Should I use `CHAR(10)` instead? That column should accept `null`, `0`, a 10-digits binary number like `1100010101`. And I need to use parse its digits. So what's your suggest? `BIT(10)` or `CHAR(10)` ?

Comment: @stack `BIT(10)` is perfectly fine - all you need to do is to get comfortable with bit operations. Bit operations are extremely fast, and bit storage is very efficient. You can set one bit or many bits at a time. You can also check for multiple set bits in a specific pattern - something that wouldn't be so easy with strings.

Comment: Great .. thank you for your explanations. And my last question: Is it possible to I update just one of its digits? I mean I want to update seventh digit *(right to left)* from `1001011101` and make it `0`. Like this: `1000011101`. Is that possible?

Comment: @stack Yes, you can update a single bit like this: `UPDATE test SET x = x & b'1110111111' WHERE id=3` If you want to set it to `1`, use `UPDATE test SET x = x | b'0001000000' WHERE id=3`. Position of `0` indicates the bit you are setting to zero. You can have more than one zero in the first example if you would like to set multiple bits to zero. Similarly, you can have more than one `1` in the second example if you need to set multiple bits to `1`.

Comment: I see. Really thanks. Also if you like you can add your explanations about *updating* in your answer for future people.

Comment: I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107776/how-to-get-the-value-of-bit-data-type-columns-in-binary-form), There is also two answers, but still I feel there will be a better solution. May you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Shafizadeh The SQL-only [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37107947/335858) is pretty good, I think. But the accepted one isn't bad either.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert `BIT` to `VARCHAR` (*or `CHAR`*) and then use `SUBSTR` in following:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),numb), 3, 1) 
FROM numbers
```

Or using `LEFT` and `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),numb),8),1)
FROM numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bit column, then use bit operations.

These are documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html).

One method is:

```
select ( (numb & b'0010000000') > 0)
```

Comment: Where is **third digit** ? And you are missing a `'`

Comment: @stack . . . The "1" is in the third digit.