# How to get the value of BIT(…) data type columns in binary form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table like this:

```
// numbers
+---------+------------+
|    id   |    numb    |
+---------+------------+
| int(11) |   bit(10)  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 0000000001 |
| 2       | 0000000101 |
| 3       | 0000000000 |
| 4       | 0000001011 |
+---------+------------+
```

When I fetch `numb` column, the result will be like this:

```
// Query
mysql> SELECT numb FROM numbers WHERE id = 2

// Fetching by PHP (pdo)
$result = $stm->fetch();
$numb   = $result['numb'];
echo $numb;
//=> 5
```

As you see, the final result is `5`. While I want to get that exact value as a string, like this `0000000101`. How can I do that?

Comment: Use [decbin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)

Comment: @Thamizhan By using that function, the result isn't always 10 digits. It will be depends on the number. `12` => `1100`, `26` => `11010`. While I want to get a binary number based 10.

Comment: Just pad zeros to it! Look at the answer section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [decbin()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) function and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for pre-pending zeros

```
<?php

$numb = 5;
echo sprintf("%010d",decbin($numb));
```

Output:

```
0000000101
```

From your comments:

```
12 - 0000001100
26 - 0000011010
```

**Update1:**

You can assign to `$numb` variable like this:

```
$numb = sprintf("%010d",decbin($result['numb']));
```

Comment: Thx .. That's correct. +1 ..! Also as a note I want to know, can I do that in the query? I mean by using something like `concat()` and making `numb`'s value as string.

Comment: @Shafizadeh So only I added [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You can assign the value similar to echo. See the updated answer

Comment: Look, forget using `sprintf()` and `decbin()` functions. I'm trying to do that by pure-sql *(not php-side)*. Is that possible? All I want to know is getting the value of a numerical column as string. Something like this *(doesn't work)*: `. . . CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),numb) active . . .`

Answer (score 3):

This is completely using SQL as you requested:

Using [CONV()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-conv-function.php) and [LPAD()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php):

```
LPAD(CONV(id,10,2),10,0)
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/521cd1/1) for you

Comment: Wait .. your fiddle isn't correct, where is `numb` column? You have created it as an alias. That's a real column in my table. In other word, `numb` column isn't related to `id` column at all.

Comment: Then add your schema or sample data here so I might help you out

Comment: @Shafizadeh Checkout the updated link: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/521cd1/1)

Comment: Better ... But in your fiddle `numb` is `integer`. May you please change it to `BIT(10)`?